# Hello human, I want to recover my little cat pics

Tags: code-golf, string, file-system

NB : Everything presented in the situation is totally fake and had just been put here to make the challenge a little more fun ;) ... Or maybe not ;)

---

=== === BEGINNING TRANSMISSION === ===

Hello,
I recently had a disk failure. I hopefully had backups and I now want my photos back. However, EVERY backup looks corrupted in the parallel universe where I live. But that's not a problem, because we had special tools to help user find their files back. They work a little bit like yours, and looks around a disk for headers that look like images. As they are still in beta, the software recovers any image it finds, gives it a random name and outputs a list containing:

- The model of the camera that took the photo, or a single `-` if not available. Note that the model could contain spaces, but no `-`.
- A tab char (`\t`, ASCII 9)
- The name of the photo file.

The file is a standard text file and looks like that:

```
[...]
-   uyfeiebsvH.jpg
-   hv754ce758.gif
-   8321214736.jpg
-   FgnvsfHJBs.jpg
-   OMGILOVYOU.jpg
-   HElloDearH.png
-   umanHAYYSG.jpg
COOLCAM S1332   umanIAYYSG.jpg
iCell 7G    1234567890.jpg
[...]
```

The file is quite big, and I can't rely on my little Ubro to move all the file that have a model in a separate directory.

---

Dear Human, I need your help. I want you to move all photos that have data about the camera in a separate directory, so I could find my little cute cat pictures out of this mess of icons, screenshots...

However, these backups are taking place on My LiquidStateDrive46X, so I don't have a lot of space left (and I'm actually downloading the Internet, so, you know, it's difficult to download something else while doing that. I just can barely surf the web and you are the only one I've found, human!)

Don't let me live that way ! Please, write my a small program that will do the work for me, and save a little Ubro.

---

- As this is code-golf, the shortest program wins
- I need to be able to launch you program, HUMAN ! So make sure your program has an existing interpreter.
- You can expect the list file to be in the directory where I launch your script. It will be named ./list.txt
- You need to move images to ./withmodel/
- Every image recovered is in the same directory from where I launch your program
- No image have a - in his name. Same goes for camera models
- It need to be a real program, not a simple function.
- No internet access, I'm DOWNLOADING! This is really important.
- I need my cat images quickly, or I can't survive: This code-golf will end on the 10th of October, if I'm still alive on this day.

=== === END OF TRANSMISSION === ===

Comment: You may use any language that have an interpreter by the time the challenge were posted, so it looks like a standard loophole, yes. I don't want to restrict too much on this...

Comment: Ok, I've edited that line to be a bit more clear, in my opinion. If you don't like it feel free to revert.

Comment: It's puuuurfect ;)! Thanks you!

Comment: I've put an answer, but I wonder if I'm missing something. Why *might* this need internet access? Is it important that the disk doesn't have much space left? Is this significant "*I cant rely on my little Ubro to move all the file that have a model in a separate directory.*"?

Comment: This should'nt need internet. I just put the rule in case... The disk has not much space left => write the shortest program possible. And the Ubro is pure storytelling, it's not significant

Comment: @DanTheMan this would be a good nickname

Comment: what's an Ubro...?

Comment: Ubro was from Ufo Brother. If you can come up with a better name, just edit :-). But anyway, it's part of the question storytelling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### PowerShell (v4), <strike>58</strike> 49 bytes

```powershell
(gc list.txt)-replace"^[^-]*`t"|mv -des withmodel


# Previous 58 byte version
(gc list.txt)-notmatch'^-'-replace".+`t"|mv -des withmodel
```

- get-content of the list
- remove camera models up to the tab by replacing them with nothing. This won't change the lines starting with "-".
- pipe into the move command, destination folder 'withmodel'. This will hit a lot of errors for the unchanged lines starting with "-", but since none of the files has a "-" in the name, that won't move any incorrect files, only the right files will be moved.

Comment: Holy crap ... I had almost the exact same thing. Finally, a challenge that PowerShell is almost *designed* for, and I was a slight bit too slow. Have a +1.

Comment: @TimmyD Indeed; it's not particularly great for golfing, but with the way "-replace" and "|mv" work on multiple things at once, this has got to be one of its strongest areas.